# Fiat Voluntas Tua — Are Mrs. Grales & Rachel allegorical characters for Mary and Jesus?

Tags: symbols, a-canticle-for-leibowitz

In Walter M. Miller, Jr.’s *A Canticle for Leibowitz*, part III — *Fiat Voluntas Tua* — we jump 600 years into the future. The Leibowitz abbey still exists, and Abbot Zerchi and New Rome prepare a mission to the colonies, so that the Catholic Church and Memorabilia might survive the all-but-inevitable destruction of Earth.

Then a nuclear warhead strikes near the abbey. Zerchi opens his doors to aid those in need and grants Doctor Cors permission to run a Green Star relief camp within the abbey — on one condition: euthanasia may not be administered or even suggested. (Victims are suffering and dying horribly from the strike and ensuing radiation poisoning.) This condition is quickly tested, forcing Cora to leave the abbey and essentially set up a euthanasia shop just up the road.

Discouraged, Zerchi encounters the two-headed mutant Mrs. Grales. Mrs. Grales, wishes to have her "sister," Rachel — essentially a mutated growth spawning from Grales’ shoulder — baptized. During the confession, a nuclear explosion destroys the abbey. Zerchi manages to survive but is trapped beneath the rubble. As he awaits his ultimate fate, Mrs. Grales comes to him; only now it is the head of Rachel that lives while Mrs. Grales slumps dead on their shoulders.

The allegorical symbolism doesn’t quite fit exactly, however there are some interesting elements which do. The most obvious is that “Rachel” effectively spawns from Grales — with the Leibowitz-universe mutants and mutations not explained all that well, this could be considered a form of immaculate conception. Additionally, after “Rachel” is baptized, she appears to ascend towards some form of supernaturally divine state in the way John the Baptist baptizes Jesus. The post-baptized Rachel seemingly free of sin and pain, and possessing miraculous powers, gives Zerchi the sacrament of communion before he dies.

Am I reading the point of these characters correctly?  Outside of U.S. English professors who might aspire to seeing symbolism everywhere, is there any proof of Miller’s inspiration for these characters of Grales & Rachel?

Comment: Yeah, that's right - it's a part of the theme of the book. Rachel is the one looked for by the Wandering Jew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most obvious interpretation is that Rachel is the [Second Coming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Coming) of Christ (although that is not the only possibility).  Human life is about to be extinguished on Earth and will never return.  (The abbot compares the spaceship's departure to the permanent expulsion from Eden.  "Remember this Earth.  Never forget her, but—never come back.")  According to Catholic dogma, Christ will some day return to Earth.  (Benjamin, if he is, as he appears to be, the [Wandering Jew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew), is awaiting that second visitation in *Fiat Lux*.)  Having not done so prior to the second nuclear war—it seems that there is no time left for Jesus to return but as the bombs are falling.

Rachel appeared as a spontaneous growth out of an old tomato-seller's shoulder.  She was not conceived sexually and thus is arguably free from the taint of original sin (as Jesus and [Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Conception) were supposed to have been).  She has never opened her eyes to the world before those final moments that Zerchi witnesses, so she has unquestionably led a blameless life and never sinned herself.  The moment the baptismal water touches her head, before Father Zerchi can even finish the Latin invocation, she takes over the ritual from him.  She needs no Holy Orders to administer Communion to Father Zerchi.

Zerchi comes to a somewhat different conclusion, however—that Rachel is merely a being born completely sinless.  At first, he rejects her authority to offer him Communion, but in his dying state, there is nothing he can do to prevent her.  However, as he watches her, he eventually decides that she is as sinless as Mary.

> He tried to refocus his eyes to get another look at the face of this being, who by gestures alone had said to him:  I do not need your first Sacrament, Man, but I am worthy to convey to you Sacrament of Life.  Now he knew what she was, and he sobbed faintly when he could not again force his eyes to focus on those cool, green, and untroubled eyes of one born free.

He sees Rachel's actions as proof that she never needed to baptized, because she was already in a state of perfect grace.  Having come to this conclusion, he wants to teach her Mary's words from *[Luke 1:46–48](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201%3A46-55&version=KJV)*:  "My soul doth magnify the Lord, and my spirit hath rejoiced in God my Saviour; for He hath regarded the lowliness of His handmaid...."  As Rachel departs, after reminding him of his soul's immortality, he thinks about her as his body dies.

> He did not ask why why God would choose to raise up a creature of primal innocence from the shoulder of Mrs. Grales, or why God gave to it the preternatural gifts of Eden—these gifts which Man had been trying to seize by brute force again from Heaven since first he lost them.  He had seen primal innocence in those eyes, and a promise of resurrection.

Either interpretation—that Rachel is the Second Incarnation, or that she is "merely" a second Immaculate Conception—is consistent with what Zerchi perceives.  Moreover, there is also a third, darker possibility, which is that the whole encounter is a hallucination on the abbot's part as he lies dying and that he is merely seeing the symbols that his mind wants to see as his life ebbs away.  Like many seemingly mystical happenings in the course of *A Canticle for Leibowitz*, nothing happens that cannot quite be explained mundanely.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, which adds several variations I had not considered. I think the Second Coming is a more accurate interpretation than an allegorical emulation of Mary begetting Jesus; there needn’t actually be a “Mary” emulative character for Jesus’s return, perhaps but for being another vessel to facilitate the Leibowitz universe’s version in form of a mutant.

Comment: A relatively minor note, but the Host Rachel gives him is already consecrated, so there's no need of Holy Orders in any case. A lay person can give Communion to the faithful either as an Extraordinary Minister of Holy Communion during Mass, at a Communion service, or eg as a minister to the sick or homebound. I received Communion from a lay minister last time I was in the hospital.

Comment: Grales also evokes Grail - a vessel that in some legends holds Christ's blood